# Data loss from class during for each iteration

Tags: java

I've got debug outputs in the constructor which all output as expected

> Incoming Parameter{C=0.620405, H=0.104122, O=0.275473} Stored
>
> Parameter{C=0.620405, H=0.104122, O=0.275473}

But when I call toString() while iterating through a list it returns an empty set.

What's causing this behavior?

```
public class PNNLEntry {
            private String matNum = "";
            private String material = "";
            private String formula = "";
            private String density = "";
            private String comment = "";
            private String references = "";
            //Map element to weight fraction as string
            private Map<String, String> elements = new TreeMap<String, String>();

        public PNNLEntry(){

        }
        public PNNLEntry(String num, String mat, String form, String dens, 
                String com, String ref, Map<String, String> elem){ 
           matNum = num;
           material = mat;
           formula = form;
           density = dens;
           comment = com;
           references = ref;
           elements = elem;
           System.out.println("Incoming Parameter" + elem.toString());
           System.out.println("Stored Parameter" + elements.toString());
           System.out.println(this.toString());
        }

@Override
public String toString(){
    String buff = "\n";

    buff += matNum;
    buff += ") " + material;
    buff += "\t" + formula;
    buff += "\n" + density;
    buff += "\n" + comment;
    buff += "\n" + elements.toString();

    buff += "\n" + references;

    return buff;
}
}
```

From the structures:

```
private static PNNLEntry entry = new PNNLEntry();
private static List<PNNLEntry> outlist = new ArrayList<PNNLEntry>();
```

Sample Output Code

```
 System.out.println("ELEMENTS \t " + elements.toString());
 entry = new PNNLEntry(matNum, material, formula, density, 
                        comment, references, elements);
 System.out.println(entry.toString());
 outlist.add(entry);
 //clear map for next element
 elements.clear();

 ...

 for(PNNLEntry output : outlist){
     System.out.println(output);
     System.out.println(output.getElements().toString());
 }
```

Outputs:

> ELEMENTS   {C=0.775501, Ca=0.018378, F=0.017422, H=0.101327,
>   N=0.035057, O=0.052316} Incoming Parameter{C=0.775501, Ca=0.018378,
>   F=0.017422, H=0.101327, N=0.035057, O=0.052316} Stored
>   Parameter{C=0.775501, Ca=0.018378, F=0.017422, H=0.101327, N=0.035057,
>   O=0.052316}
>
> 1) A-150 Tissue-Equivalent Plastic (A150TEP)  -
>   1.127000 The above density is estimated to be accurate to 4 significant digits.  Uncertainties are not addressed. The following
>   data were calculated from the input weight fractions {C=0.775501,
>   Ca=0.018378, F=0.017422, H=0.101327, N=0.035057, O=0.052316} Density
>   and weight fractions from
>   http://physics.nist.gov/cgi-bin/Star/compos.pl?matno=099 (NIST 1998).

...

> 1) A-150 Tissue-Equivalent Plastic (A150TEP)  -
>   1.127000 The above density is estimated to be accurate to 4 significant digits.  Uncertainties are not addressed. The following
>   data were calculated from the input weight fractions {} Density and
>   weight fractions from
>   http://physics.nist.gov/cgi-bin/Star/compos.pl?matno=099 (NIST 1998).

So the only data that is being lost is the map data that was passed.

My best guess currently is an aliasing problem with clearing the map after it's passed to the class constructor, but I'm not certain if that's it or how best to resolve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the problem:

```
elements.clear();
```

Recall that inside of your constructor, you're doing this:

```
elements = elem;
```

...where `elements` represents your field and `elem` represents what you've passed in.  This means that they're pointing to the same reference.

You're trying to reset the state of the map, which is admirable, but that's not necessary.  You could do one of two things:

- New up an instance of a map when you're trying to insert things...
- ...or use `HashMap`'s [copy constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#HashMap(java.util.Map)):

  ```
  elements = new HashMap<>(elem);
  ```

Comment: That's what I was expecting was the culprit, but getting this detailed response really gives me the comprehension of the goings on.

However, the map state reset is fundamentally required, as the loop populates a map which is passed to the object.  There are 300 such maps being generated and passed, so the referencing issue is pretty important to know about.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like this line in your sample output code is clearing elements before you get to the for loop...

```
elements.clear();
```